# Is there any way to clone a reference type into an owned type?

Tags: reference, rust, clone, ownership

I have a method that I want to return an owned copy of an element. I can justify why I want this if needed.

Here is a minimal reproducible example: ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c78bf8c95f2e5aeb001eb7dfcaa1f469))

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct AsciiDisplayPixel {
    value: char,
    color: u32,
}

struct PieceToPixelMapper {
    map: HashMap<usize, AsciiDisplayPixel>,
}

impl PieceToPixelMapper {
    pub fn map(&self, index: usize) -> Option<AsciiDisplayPixel> {
        let pixel = self.map.get(&index);
        let pixel = match pixel {
            None => return None,
            Some(x) => x,
        };

        return Some(pixel.clone());
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello World");
}
```

This fails to compile with

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:20:21
   |
20 |         return Some(pixel.clone());
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `AsciiDisplayPixel`, found reference
   |
   = note: expected type `AsciiDisplayPixel`
              found type `&AsciiDisplayPixel`
```

I'm not sure why this is the case. According to the [documentation on clone](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html#tymethod.clone), it looks like the resulting type of `clone` be whatever the parent was, so if you clone a reference, you still get a reference, which I guess if fine, but then I have no clue how I clone to owned data. `to_owned` seems to have the exact same problem and gives the same error message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`AsciiDisplayPixel` needs to implement `Clone` for you to be able to clone (`Copy`, `Debug`, and others probably make sense too):

```
#[derive(Clone)]
struct AsciiDisplayPixel {
    value: char,
    color: u32,
}
```

[(updated playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8e4777aee7f97e3a33c7f660cb58d4c0)

at which point the implementation can be simplified to:

```
pub fn map(&self, index: usize) -> Option<AsciiDisplayPixel> {
    self.map.get(&index).cloned()
}
```

Comment: `map` is actually a `HashMap<usize, AsciiDisplayPixel>`. So `pixel` is a `&AsciiDisplayPixel`. I've edited my question to include a full reproducible example.

Comment: @TechnoSam: The issue there is that `AsciiDisplayPixel` isn’t `Clone`.

Comment: Thank you very much, that seems so obvious in hindsight!

Comment: Isn't it surprising that instead of refusing to compile, `.clone()´ - in the abstence of `Clone` - provides a reference. It's like "oh we cannot produce an apple but let's see if an orange would do". Was expecting Rust not to do these, but require explicitness. -- I'll write ".clone() as T" from now on, to make sure.